# How to extract table data from a website only AFTER inputting data?

Tags: python, html, web, flask, beautifulsoup

There is a website which doesn't take queries (hidden), there is an input field with an html id, once u enter value and click submit, you get a single row table.

Is it possible to enter input values in a loop and get the table data by web scraping using python along with beautifulsoup or flask? (Not selenium)

[link](https://pesuacademy.com/Academy)

Click on Know your class & section

```
`import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Set the URL you want to webscrape from
url = 'https://www.pesuacademy.com/Academy'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
#results = soup.find(id = "knowClsSectionModalLoginId")
#R = soup.find(id = 'knowClsSectionModalTableDate')
try:
  a = soup.find('input', {'id':'knowClsSectionModalLoginId'}).get('value')
  for i in a:
    inputv = i.get('value')
    print(i, \n)

except:
  pass
`
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post there some sample input data for which the site returns some output?

Comment: Done, but no result, ik im wrong

Comment: And can you put to your question some concrete values for which the site returns some output (like SRN, Dept Id or Mobile Number)?

Comment: PES1201900004  for srn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to "Know your Class & Section". This is a form.
This is an ajax post call with the `loginid`.

You can give all the ids in list `loginids`. The script loops through and gets all the data and saves to a csv file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

loginids = ["PES1201900004"]

payload = {
    "loginId": ""
}

headers = {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
url = "https://pesuacademy.com/Academy/getStudentClassInfo"

columns = ['PRN', 'SRN', 'Name', 'Class', 'Section', 'Cycle', 'Department', 'Branch', 'Institute Name']

data = []

for logins in loginids:
    payload["loginId"] = logins

    res = requests.post(url, data=payload,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    data.append([i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.find("table").find("tbody").find_all("td")])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             PRN SRN            Name Class Section Cycle Department  Branch Institute Name
0  PES1201900004  NA  AKSHAYA RAMESH                  NA             B ARCH
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, what's headers?

Comment: They are components of http requests. Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: loginids = []
for i in range(0,60):
  loginids.append("PES120190000"+str(i).zfill(4))

If i try this, it's throwing AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Check if those login ids are available using the browser. If they are invalid, then you won't get proper html response back